# In which filter does spring store the accessed url, before redirecting to the login page?

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-security

In Spring security (3.0.6), if we try to access a page, and the session times out, we are taken to the login page, and upon successful authentication, we are redirected to the very page that we had tried to access before we were taken to the login page. Where, in the filter interceptor chain, is this 'last-accessed' url saved ?

I wish to modify this 'last accessed' url in the particular case when it redirects to '/exitUser'. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A copy of the incoming request is cached (not just the URL), before redirecting to the login page. The `ExceptionTranslationFilter` realises that a login is required and passes the request to the configured instance of `RequestCache`. There is a basic description in [the reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#request-caching).

You can access the `SavedRequest` by requesting it from the `RequestCache`. By default it is stored in the session, so creating an `HttpSessionRequestCache` will give you the required functionality. You can also customize the `RequestCache` if you wish by using the [namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-request-cache).

The actual redirect, which uses the saved request, is performed by the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` instance. You can customize that if you want to change the redirect for a successful login. You'll find more on that in the manual and also in previous SO questions.

Comment: I extended SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler and configured that in <form-login> as authentication-success-handler-ref. It did the job